# sympy will produce a zero derivative when it is not

Tags: python, sympy

Here is a code sample for the problem.

```
from sympy import Function, symbols, diff, cos,sin
x,y = symbols('x y') 
f, g = symbols("f g", cls=Function)
g = g(x)
f= f(g) # function composition here
dfdx=diff(f,x)  # chain rule here
dfdx
```

The output is given next:
[image]

Now, for

```
xi = symbols('xi')
dfdx.subs([(xi, sin(x)), (f, cos(xi)),(g, sin(x))])
```

The output is:
[image]

And, finally for

```
dfdx.subs([(xi, sin(x)), (f, cos(xi)),(g, sin(x))]).doit()
```

The output is 0.  Why? it should not. The only thing different between the two previous lines is the `.doit()` at the end. If you evaluate the derivative by hand it would be cos(x) (-sin(sin(x)). It should be clear that the evaluation at the end of the vertical bar should be **after** and not before taking the derivative.

Comment: For me your `[2]` gives output with separate `xi` and `_xi` symbols. Your substitutions looked similar to me to `[(f, cos(g)), (g, sin(x))]`, so I tested those, and they gave your expected result.

Comment: @DanGetz : Could you please send me your script?  Thanks.

Comment: @DanGets:  I got it. thanks.  NO need to send me your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your symbol xi will not match the one that is generated implicitly by the other substitution:

```
In [53]: dfdx
Out[53]: 
  d            d       
─────(f(g(x)))⋅──(g(x))
dg(x)          dx      

In [54]: dfdx.subs(f, cos(xi))
Out[54]: 
d          d          
──(g(x))⋅─────(cos(ξ))
dx       dg(x)        

In [55]: dfdx.subs(f, cos(xi)).subs(g, sin(x))
Out[55]: 
d          ⎛d         ⎞│        
──(sin(x))⋅⎜──(cos(ξ))⎟│        
dx         ⎝dξ        ⎠│ξ=sin(x)

In [56]: dfdx.subs(f, cos(xi)).subs(g, sin(x)).atoms()
Out[56]: {1, ξ, x, ξ}

In [57]: srepr(dfdx.subs(f, cos(xi)).subs(g, sin(x)).atoms())
Out[57]: "{Integer(1), Symbol('xi'), Symbol('x'), Dummy('xi', dummy_index=1433950)}"
```

Note that the second symbol xi is a Dummy symbol and is considered to be a distinct symbol from the `xi` that you defined. The derivative is with respect to two different symbols like:

```
In [61]: d = Derivative(cos(x), y)

In [62]: d
Out[62]: 
d         
──(cos(x))
dy        

In [63]: d.doit()
Out[63]: 0
```

Comment: @ Oscar Benjamin :  Thanks for your help here. See that the your Out[55] box indicates that the first factor is d/dx sin(x) = cos(X). Then the second factor d/d xi  (cos (xi) |_xi=sin(x) is -sin(xi) and evaluating -sin( sin(x)).  Then it might be that ``SymPy`` is fooling the user with its notation.  Still, I would like to find the value of the expression, so if there is a way around I would appreciate it.